# mysql IF conditioned by another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following simple Inbox simulated query (for mail purposes)

```
SELECT * FROM inbox 
WHERE receiver_id=:receiver_id 
AND receiver_type='a' 
AND spam!='y' 
ORDER by date DESC, time DESC 
LIMIT :paging OFFSET :offset
```

**Inbox** table has regular fields such as subject, mail_body, date, time etc.
It also contains a flag (sender_type) that can be "**C**", "**L**", "**A**" and (sender_id)

I want to include an **extra field** at the end of (SELECT *) that is named **ext** which contains the extension of the image for that particular type of user (so i can display the image - image format is **id, ext** meaning $id . $ext - 1.jpg, 2.png etc....

I think doing 1 query is better than what I do now, which is the main query above,
and then for each entry i scan the particular table for type C, L and A users, and requesting the corresponding **ext** for their particular id (sender_id) so I can display their picture.

Would it be useful (and also possible) to add **ext** extension of image of each type of user in the above SELECT ? I assume it's done with the IF statement, but don't really know how. It's not really simple thing.

I grab **ext** from 3 different tables myl_u, mya_u and myc_c for **L**, **A** and **C** type of users.

The **L** **A** and **C** tables are queried like

```
SELECT l_id, ext, name, .. FROM myl_u
SELECT a_id, ext, name, .. FROM myl_a
SELECT c_id, ext, name, .. FROM myc_c
```

in INBOX table, **sender_id** corresponds to **l_id**, **a_id** and **c_id**

Comment: http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/ take a look here, a simple tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join all the tables on the sender ID and then use the `IFNULL` method to only grab the right ext.

```
SELECT *
       , IFNULL(TL.ext, IFNULL(TA.ext, TC.ext)) as ext
       , IFNULL(TL.name, IFNULL(TA.name, TC.name)) as name
FROM inbox AS T1

LEFT JOIN myl_u AS TL ON T1.sender_id=TL.l_id AND T1.sender_type='L'
LEFT JOIN mya_u AS TA ON T1.sender_id=TA.a_id AND T1.sender_type='A'
LEFT JOIN myc_c AS TC ON T1.sender_id=TC.c_id AND T1.sender_type='C'

WHERE receiver_id=:receiver_id 
AND receiver_type='a' 
AND spam!='y' 
ORDER by date DESC, time DESC 
LIMIT :paging OFFSET :offset
```

Comment: I see...will try it. Also quick question. Is it better to LEFT JOIN these tables (myl_u has approx. 4000 records, mya_u has approx 15k and myc_c has approx 20k) in this query or just do my old query and for each 8 results that display at once, query once the appropriate table (myl_u, mya_u or myc_c) for 1 row containing the ext (for image).

Comment: To be honest I have the feeling your database structure isnt realy optimized considering the tables/names you used, but I could be wrong. If you have the right keys in place the performance should be no issue. But then again, just retrieving 8 records seperately shouldnt be a big problem either and might be faster if the database isnt optimized

Comment: managed to implement your solution in 2 of the places on my website. Apparently, even tho' my 3 tables are not yet populated with the figures I said above, 4k, 15k and 20k records, and have around 20-30 rows each, your solution scores an average of 0.011 - 0.012 seconds while the previous solution I had scored 0.015 - 0.018 seconds, so yours is better so far. Don't know for heavily populated users sections, but I think 1 mysql read is better than 9 consecutive, because of the I/O with the hdd

Comment: i'm still thinking if 1 optimised fast query + 8 subsequent small queries would be the choice against the one that's optimised but has 3 left joins that in the future will lookup through ~50k of rows

Comment: If you have 8 sub queries (eg all on the 20k table) the database has to go trough 20k records 8 times. Now with the proper keys that will be quite fast. When using a join however mysql will mostlikely go trough those 20k records just once and pick out all the records it needs. That is when the db is setup properly, which apparently you have.

Comment: i think I thought well my tables right from the beginning, and also all the way through implementation. not my first project and stuff :) the only thing I would have done differently, for the organizing things 's sake would have been foreign keys if you askme (with my whole project). took time to rewrite a ton of old mysql_* into PDO queries (took about 2 months and half or even more, of intense coding)....now to the question..I think u're right...i crunched a bit this problem in my head today, and thought of the memory the JOINS occupy, on the PHP side...

Comment: I think having 3 queries on 20K tables, 2 queries on 50K table, and 2 queries on 150k table (with right indexing) is better than 1 query on JOINS that fill the memory with 20K + 50K + 150K all at once, and mysqld having to compile the right ones...I know technically it's just slightly faster, i tested it on what i have and it gave few significant milliseconds less....but with right indexing I think for now I'll rest my case and stick with what I have...nevertheless, I will start the optimising of all my queries (and I have stuff I can optimise easily) and will weigh again everything soon...:)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think mysql is smart enough to notice that that there are no elements of the JOIN in the WHERE or ORDER BY clause of the query. And so the will first execute the main query to get the 8 main records and then join the other tables on those records.